# Python return list from nth element from sublist

Tags: python, list

is there a way to:
starting with a list
lst=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]

i want a new list with every second(nth) element from the sublist
new list: [2,5,8,11]

and or
a new list with every second(nth) element from lst[1:3]
new list: [5,8]

thanks in advance

Comment: please make an attempt and share before asking [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a recurring operation, you'll probably want to turn this into a reusable function. Feel free to remove the type annotations.

```py
def get_nth_elements(list_of_lists: List[List[Any]], n: int) -> List[Any]:
   """Get the nth element from each list in a given list of lists"""
   return [sub_list[n] for sub_list in list_of_lists]
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a new list with every second element from the entire list , you can do the following:

```
new_list = [lst[i][1] for i in range(len(lst))]
```

Comment: Why not just `[sublist[1] for sublist in lst]`?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was looking for

```
lst2=[sublist[1] for sublist in lst[1:3]]
```